# Unable to resize partition C drive is Sandwiched

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, uefi

So as you see from the title i am trying to expand the C: Drive but an 
GPT(Reserved Partition) is blocking it i cant seem to move the partition.

I can only move the EFI System Partition.

I have a system restore disk with me so i can fix any problem that occurs.

MiniTool:

[image: MiniTool]

Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]

> EDIT: Tried to move EFI System Partition to expand C drive but did not work.
>
> Disk Management (EFI MOVED) – Expand Disk is grayed out:
>
> [image: Disk Management (EFI MOVED)]

Comment: Is it worth potentially breaking your Windows installation just to gain 451MB of space? Why not just create a new partition in the unallocated space and set it up so it acts as a second drive in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft rules that Extend Volume feature in Disk Management only works to a RAW or NTFS partition

By using MiniTool, you can move FAT32 system partition, but GPT(Reserved Partition)’s file system is Other, can’t be moved, try to select the GPT(Reserved Partition) and then click the function "Extend Partition" from MiniTool action panel.

Comment: So Extend the GPT then shrink then extend the C drive? i dont get it

Comment: Btw i can not Expand the GPT(Reserved Partition)